# Why do I get a segmentation fault when I don't have print statements in my Johnson-Trotter algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to implement the Johnson-Trotter algorithm in C++ for a homework assignment. I was really excited after (I thought) I figured it out, but as it turns out I get a seg fault when I run it. Here's the code for it (sorry it's a little long):

```
#include <iostream>

#define N   3
#define RIGHT   true
#define LEFT    false

using namespace std;

// Struct to represent a number with its arrow and its mobility
struct number {
    int num;
    bool arrow;
};

void printPermutation(number permutation[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (permutation[i].arrow == LEFT)
            cout << '-';
        cout << permutation[i].num << ' ';
    }
}

void reverseArrows(number permutation[], int n, int k) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (permutation[i].num > permutation[k].num)
            permutation[i].arrow ^= 1;
}

void swapMobile(number permutation[], int k) {
    number temp;
    temp.num = permutation[k].num;
    temp.arrow = permutation[k].arrow;

    int swapper;
    if (permutation[k].arrow == RIGHT)
        swapper = 1;
    else    // permutation[k].arrow == LEFT
        swapper = -1;

    permutation[k].num = permutation[k + swapper].num;
    permutation[k].arrow = permutation[k + swapper].arrow;
    permutation[k + swapper].num = temp.num;
    permutation[k + swapper].arrow = temp.arrow;
}

void setNextPermutation(number current[], number next[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        next[i].num = current[i].num;
        next[i].arrow = current[i].arrow;
    }
}

bool isMobile(number permutation[], int n, int k) {
    if ((k == 0) && (permutation[k].arrow == LEFT))
        return false;
    if ((k == n - 1) && (permutation[k].arrow == RIGHT))
        return false;
    if ((permutation[k].arrow == LEFT) && (permutation[k - 1].num < permutation[k].num))
        return true;
    if ((permutation[k].arrow == RIGHT) && (permutation[k].num > permutation[k + 1].num))
        return true;
    return false;
}

int largestMobile(number permutation[], int n) {
    int largest = 0;
    cout << "Before isMobile\n";
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if (i > largest && isMobile(permutation, n, i))
            largest = i;
    return largest;
}

bool hasMobile(number permutation[], int n) {
    cout << "Before isMobile\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (isMobile(permutation, n, i))
            return true;
    return false;
}

// Simple function to iteratively calculate n!
int factorial(int n) {
    int factorial = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        factorial *= i;
    return factorial;
}

void JohnsonTrotter(int n) {
    cout << "Before factorial\n";
    int nFactorial = factorial(n);

    number permutations[nFactorial][n];

    // Initialize first permutation.
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        permutations[0][i].num = i + 1;
        permutations[0][i].arrow = LEFT;
    }

    int permutation = 0;
    cout << "Before hasMobile\n";
    while (hasMobile(permutations[permutation], n)) {
        cout << "Before setNextPermutation\n";
        setNextPermutation(permutations[permutation], permutations[permutation + 1], n);
        permutation++;
        cout << "Before largestMobile\n";
        int k = largestMobile(permutations[permutation], n);
        cout << "Before swapMobile\n";
        swapMobile(permutations[permutation], k);
        cout << "Before reverseArrows\n";
        reverseArrows(permutations[permutation], n, k);
    }

    cout << "Before printPermutation\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < nFactorial; i++) {
        printPermutation(permutations[i], n);
        cout << ' ';
        if (!((i + 1) % n))
            cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    JohnsonTrotter(N);

    return 0;
}
```

I first ran it without any print statements and it gave me a seg fault. I threw in some print statements and I didn't get a seg fault, but I didn't get my expected results either. I removed the print statements, changed `N` to 2, and got a seg fault again. I changed `N` to 1 and got an expected result. I changed `N` to 4 and got a seg fault with and without print statements.

Also, sorry if this is the wrong way to ask this but I've never asked a question on here before.

Comment: You can enable address sanitizer. In many cases it is able to tell you where the error happened: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hhpzDFvXopk

Comment: The `setNextPermutation(permutations[permutation], permutations[permutation + 1], n);` is invoked with `permutations` growing unbounded. eventually it will breach the declared size of `permutations` and invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Using address sanitizer, you can see that the error happens at line 48 inside `setNextPermutation` in this line: `next[i].num = current[i].num;`, in which you dereference an address outside of the allocated buffer. see here: https://godbolt.org/z/7s573fY9r for yourself.

Comment: The last printed output (or its absence) give you a hint on where the fault occurs. Tell us. You can also nail it down by adding more cout's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who responded. You all were right about it trying to access more elements than there was memory allocated for the array. I found the main culprit in my `largestMobile` function. Here is the refactored code:

```cpp
int largestMobile(number permutation[], int n) {
    int k = 0;
    while (!isMobile(permutation, n, k))
        k++;
    if (k < n - 1)
        for (int i = k + 1; i < n; i++)
            if (permutation[i].num > permutation[k].num && isMobile(permutation, n, i))
                k = i;
    return k;
}
```

Small (obvious) note: I changed the variable name `largest` to just `k` to make more room on one line and also it makes sense since that's what I'll be returning anyway. I finally checked to see whether the element I would be returning is mobile. The previous version never checked if `largest` was mobile or not. Also in the previous version, if the largest element in `permutation` was in the front of the array, no other element could possibly be larger and so `largest` was never updated.

Also, in `swapMobile`, `k` needed to be updated as well.